# How to save weekly, bi-weekly and mothly orders

Tags: c#, php, mysql

First of all sorry for the weird topic title, but I realy don't know how to explain my problem in a short title.

I'm developing an application, which should contain all the orders for my company. Most orders are weekly or daily, so there is no problem there. I just save the delivery day's bitwise in my database (1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 4 = Wednesday... etc).

Some orders are only bi-weekly or come every 28 days. And to make things more complex some files do only come bi-weekly but have 2 seperate files.

When the orders come in two serperate files i also need two records on my reports. So I can't ignore the facts that there are two files.

How can I save this data the easiest in my database? And how do I retrieve this in the simplest way as possbile? I've thought about making a CHAR(4) record in my database and entering for instance:

- 1111 weekly
- 0101 bi-weekly (even weeks)
- 1010 bi-weekly (odd weeks)
- 0001 monthy (every 4th week)
- 0202 bi-weekly (every even week 2 files)

But i think this method is hard to query on because I have to query on the n-th character based on the modulo of the current week.

Can you provide me with examples or documentation about this subject?

P.s. The data is stored in a mysql database, I manage the data in a software program which i write in C# and the reporting is done with PHP.

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: why don't you have a seperate table called intervals, and keep all intervals there with their id's. and in your primary table just add the foreign key of interval id

Answer (score 1):

How about 2 fields: period and interval.
Period contains day, week, months, etc. and interval explains itself I think. This gives you almost unlimited flexibility to store your interval.

Personally I'd be reluctant to use bit-wise logic for this kind of application. It quickly grows too complex and querying is hard.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
I realy like the idea, but what do you suggest to enter in interval? And shouldn't you also have a start date (or week). And how do you store whether there are 2 files?

Comment: We also don't have a very large set of options. As 28 days is the maximum we are allowed to deliver. So I've got 7 options (weekly, 2x bi-weekly, 4x monthly) and a flag for multiple files.